# Typescript: If multiSelect is true, then I want to change the types

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings, react-typescript, conditional-types

currently I have some troubles with typescript.
I have a React component, where some typescript definitions should change, when `multiSelect` is true. `onUpdate` and `value` will be forced to a string OR string[] when `multiSelect` is true or false. But is doesn't work.

```
export interface DefaultUserTypeFieldProps {
    className?: string;
    disabled?: boolean;
    /**
     * The label of the input
     */
    label?: string;
    autoSelectUserId?: string;
}

export interface SingleUserTypeFieldProps extends DefaultUserTypeFieldProps {
    multiSelect: false;
    value: string;
    onUpdate: (value: string, isValid: boolean) => void;
}

export interface MultipleUserTypeFieldProp extends DefaultUserTypeFieldProps {
    multiSelect: true;
    value: string[];
    onUpdate: (value: string[], isValid: boolean) => void;
}

export type UserTypeFieldProps = SingleUserTypeFieldProps | MultipleUserTypeFieldProp;
```

The React component looks like this

```
export const UserTypeField = (props: UserTypeFieldProps) => {
const {
    className,
    label,
    disabled,
    value,
    autoSelectUserId,
    multiSelect = false,
    onUpdate,
} = props;

const handleSelectUser = (selectedUserIds: string[]) => {
    close();
    if (multiSelect) {
        onUpdate(selectedUserIds, true);
    } else {
        onUpdate(selectedUserIds[0], true);
    }
};

return ...;
```

};

In `handleSelectUser` I get the error `TS2345: Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string & string[]'. Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'string[]'.`. As you can see, it is connected with a & but in the interface definition you can see that I use conditional types with |.
Do you have any ideas ?

Thank for your help!

Comment: Just use `as`. Like `onUpdate(selectedUserIds as string[])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in `destructuring`. TS has problems with it :)

```js
export interface DefaultUserTypeFieldProps {
    className?: string;
    disabled?: boolean;
    /**
     * The label of the input
     */
    label?: string;
    autoSelectUserId?: string;
}

export interface SingleUserTypeFieldProps extends DefaultUserTypeFieldProps {
    multiSelect: false;
    value: string;
    onUpdate: (value: string, isValid: boolean) => void;
}

export interface MultipleUserTypeFieldProp extends DefaultUserTypeFieldProps {
    multiSelect: true;
    value: string[];
    onUpdate: (value: string[], isValid: boolean) => void;
}

export type UserTypeFieldProps = SingleUserTypeFieldProps | MultipleUserTypeFieldProp;



export const UserTypeField = (props: UserTypeFieldProps) => {
// problem is here
    const {
        className,
        label,
        disabled,
        value,
        autoSelectUserId,
        multiSelect = false,
        onUpdate,
    } = props;

    const handleSelectUser = (selectedUserIds: string[]) => {
        close();
        if (props.multiSelect) {
// here is the fix
            props.onUpdate(selectedUserIds, true);
        } else {
            props.onUpdate(selectedUserIds[0], true);
        }
    };

    return null
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgEWCwFcAbGAVQGc0AVATzGADEFhSATABSgjCrgBvAFBwxcbKUxUqAOUwBbYAH4AXHCowoyAOYBuUeI4IqmAEalgHNXDMQIlzEgPi4AegBUHw%20I9xaABZ4UmbscBDocDBBiEhgxDA%20Yh5uSSHsNpraSPpJmAkQAMrswNiUNFAAktbqWboGAL7CwqCQsLGoGDh4hbqW1HSMLGycPHwCoKhIHAKEJOQDUAxMrOzcvPxCSQpkMAjFlmXqWKQ0LuIAbpikxMC1WvVJEEgUYByYqOoAFFc3dxoPHIAGkQVAAatcEBx1HYHMAnABKOAAXgAfHALhAoY1mq1oPBkJ0sLg4ABZXYIMD9CrLYZrMZgOCTYDTWZEfILGlDVajDYCESuHbkfYlI5RKC3c5iX63e7ZHQAbQAulLwi83h9-j9rrKAfLlSCTBDSFCYfZHEgkWiMViODiWuB8VEhnBFrSeetxii4L0ctTBisRp7NgAfMkUqnAN3coMMgzNB1teDYZ6aV1cwNrb1fMB89TRzO88ZW9EiJIppBpgWucSSaRyRTAIFJVzpUjNmtGEzmSwcDudjE6pst8T5GBFUXlNDVfudoV7A6leDIuAnGizmvPV7vVAbhre3PjeOuCtpgJODiWRdlRbZmiHVAcRbVKhy3TKktbAcSUgQGhfBFVVcBBIhzPkADp5xFB8kWrb8xEPfhwK3DVUC%20e8lysZ8ZhBLRbkAkcxH3dgaC-eCEIglCd2AdDJywioXwVAAGJVcIlYACO-JpXAaY9xCgYAYGIKAkDgJAyFIYQmmEIA)

Just use `props.onUpdate` instead of `onUpdate`.

I believe such behaviour is logged in gtihub issues but unable to find a link

**UPDATE**

If it still don't work, please enable `strictNullChecks`
Thanks @Roberto Zvjerković for the tip!

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27497

Comment: Crazy, one case is working and the other not :/ 
Here is a image: https://imgur.com/zPMq9Qb

Comment: @JanHöck it is strange, because it works in TS playground. WHich version of TS do you have?

Comment: I have `"typescript": "^4.2.2",` and your playground looks broken to me :) https://imgur.com/aYXoCFE did you saved ?

Comment: try to close and open this file in your IDE, maybe it is a cache

Comment: Add `if(props.multiSelect === false)`, you probably don't have `strictNullChecks`

Comment: @JanHöck regarding playground, some times it happens. Just copy/paste my code from the answer

Comment: @RobertoZvjerković thanks, the problem is in `strictNullChecks`

Comment: `if(!props.multiSelect)` checks against `undefined` and `null` as well. You should use `strictNullChecks` compiler flag

Comment: Big thanks to you too! It works now like a chaaaaarm

Comment: Explanation: when you destructure the object the properties become independent variables with independent types.  So you need to keep the object together in order to preserve the relationship between the props.